# Cannot get Bluetooth to work on Lenovo ThinkPad T15 Intel Gen 2 (Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 card) running Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, intel, firmware, bluez

I hope someone here can help me get Bluetooth working on my Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 card (Lenovo ThinkPad T15 Intel Gen 2). I don't usually ask for help, but I'm at my wit's end now...

**Basic info about my Arch configuration:**

```bsh
uname -r
5.12.8-arch1-1

sudo lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             724992  16 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  11 nfc,bluetooth,thinkpad_acpi,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4

sudo pacman -Q bluez bluez-utils linux-firmware linux-headers
bluez 5.58-1
bluez-utils 5.58-1
linux-firmware 20210511.7685cf4-1
linux-headers 5.12.8.arch1-1

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-05-30 16:49:39 CEST; 4min 55s ago
     [...]

sudo lsusb
[...]
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp.

sudo rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
[...]
```

As can be seen from the previous information, I am using the latest Linux kernel along with the latest Linux firmware. I have also already matched the latest official drivers from Intel with those under `/lib/firmware`, they are identical. Nevertheless, it is not possible for me to see/use the Bluetooth adapter via `sudo bluetoothctl list` (No default controller available).

Normally I would suspect that the Linux firmware simply does not support the adapter yet, however it is listed as confirmed certified supported for [Ubuntu](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/8087:0032) and the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop/Lenovo#T_series) also states this.

**As far as I can see there are also no error messages in the log:**

```
sudo journalctl | grep hci0
Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 0
Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader timestamp 2019.40 buildtype 1 build 38
Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 0
Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader timestamp 2019.40 buildtype 1 build 38
Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1444061 usecs
Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 26828 usecs
Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-0041-0041.ddc
Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2021.15 buildtype 1 build 23884
```

Even though the firmware could not be loaded correctly the first time according to the log (`Failed to send firmware data (-38)`), it succeeds on the second attempt (`Firmware loaded in 1444061 usecs`). According to this, it should work, right?

Does anyone have an idea or am I not following something correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a regression between 5.11 and 5.13 - I am working on narrowing it down, see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1985787